# Custom XPath rule raises violation in pmd but not in sonar

Tags: sonarqube, pmd

I have a quite strange behavior.

I create a XPath rule for PMD 4.2.6 in a file named pmd-extensions.xml :

```
...
<rule name="AvoidPrintStackTrace-XPath"
  message="Avoid to use printStackTrace - XPath"
  class="net.sourceforge.pmd.rules.XPathRule">
  <description>Avoid to use printStackTrace - XPath</description>
  <properties>
    <property name="xpath">
     <value>
<![CDATA[
//Name[contains (@Image, "printStackTrace")]
]]>
     </value>
    </property>
  </properties>
  <example>
  <![CDATA[
    // don't do this! 
    myException.printStackTrace() 
   ]]>
   </example>
</rule>
...
```

I have an unit test validating this rule and working fine:

```
 ...
 @Before
 public void setUp() {
     addRule("rulesets/pmd-extensions.xml", "AvoidPrintStackTrace-XPath");
 }
 ...
```

But when I embed this rule in Sonar, the rule doesn't fire any violation while I expected one:

```
 ...
 <rule key="AvoidPrintStackStrace-XPath" >
  <name>AvoidPrintStackStrace-XPath</name>
  <configKey>rulesets/pmd-extensions.xml/AvoidPrintStackTrace-XPath</configKey>
  <category name="Usability"/>
  <description>Avoid to use printStackTrace - XPath</description>
 </rule>
 ...
```

And if I declare this rule directly in Sonar (with same XPath expression), the rule fire a violation as expected:

```
...
<rule key="AvoidPrintStackStrace-XPath-Sonar" priority="MAJOR">
 <name><![CDATA[AvoidPrintStackStrace-XPath-Sonar]]></name>
 <configKey><![CDATA[net.sourceforge.pmd.rules.XPathRule]]></configKey>
 <category name="Maintainability"/>
 <description>Avoid to use printStackTrace - XPath-Sonar</description>
 <param key="xpath" type="s">
  <description><![CDATA[XPath expressions.]]></description>
  <defaultValue>//Name[contains (@Image, "printStackTrace")]</defaultValue>
 </param>
 <param key="message" type="s">
  <description><![CDATA[Message to display when a violation occurs.]]></description>
  <defaultValue>Prevent use of printStackTrace</defaultValue>
 </param>
</rule>
...
```

What's wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't added this new rule to the profile that you are using for your project.

The fact that you provided a "pmd-extensions.xml" file just means that you added this rule to the rule repository. But if you do not activate this rule on a single profile, it will remain inactive and will never get executed.

Comment: I have ticked the rule in the profile and this profile is used for the analysis, so this is not the reason (in fact other custom rules embedded in the JAR and activated are called and raise violation, while this one doesn't).